# how to use js to do a loop

Tags: javascript, html

i want to use js this function:
i have a string[] s={"11111","2222","33333",...} how to 
achieve the html body

```
<h2>total s.length </h2>
<p>s[0]</p>
<p>s[1]</p>
<p>s[2]</p>
```

because s.length and content is uncertain,so i cannot  one  by one  print,i want to use javascript,can you tell me how,i know little about js knowledge.thank you

Comment: So in JavaScript it would be `var s=["11111","2222","33333",...]`.

Comment: As per the comments in the answer: are you using Java/JSP? If so, why exactly would you like to use JavaScript for this and not Java/JSP? Aren't you confusing JSP *scriptlets* with JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arr = ["11111","2222","33333"];
var output = "<h2>total " + arr.length + "</h2>" + "<p>" + arr.join("</p><p>") + "</p>";
document.getElementById("OutputPanel").innerHTML = output;
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TQSK4/

You better add the result into existing container in the document, like in the example, not write directly to the document.

Comment: +1 nice...I was expecting a loop with a lot of `createElement` calls.

Comment: @sje397 thanks, if you need to store those elements for later use or manipulate them somehow this might require loop with createElement, but in this simple case one element is more than enough. :-)

Comment: There is a </p> missing in the end. Otherwise this is a good solution.

Comment: html is only part of java app ,i want  arr=s, so the content of s  is uncertain, not only have three Value, maybe include "444","555",the var arr how to get the uncertain value,in your code very well,but only solve one my problem,can you help me this

Comment: @Mikael thanks for the heads, up - code is now fixed. Wonder why the OP accepted this then unaccepted.. :{

Comment: @pengwang you can have how many items as you want, even 12: `var arr = ["11111","2222","33333", "11111","2222","33333", "11111","2222","33333", "11111","2222","33333"];` so I'm not sure what's the problem.

Comment: sorry,may be I didn't explained it very detailed, arr need Dynamic get value

Comment: i want to know if i can var arr = s, s is java array as string[] s

Comment: @pengwang you tagged this as JavaScript, not Java. If it's really Java please re-tag the question and edit your original post.

Comment: in javascript var arr cannot Dynamic get value? the value is unknown until i do one the other thins

Comment: var arr = ["11111","2222","33333", "11111","2222","33333", "11111","2222","33333", "11111","2222","33333"]  this is Early already know the exact value

Comment: @pengwang sorry I have no idea what you're talking about. Try to explain how this array is being created maybe this will explain some things here.